# Change the content type to email in sharepoint

Tags: content-type

we have few emails uploaded with wrong content type in a library. we want them to change them email content type. but the problem is, we cant have the metadata like from,to body etc as it was uploaded using wrong content type.

Manually re-uploading the emails with email content type will do but there are lot of them. so this is not feasible.

Any other way we can achieve this? changing the content type to email and have all the metadata of the same?